# Generating large file using Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am running the following dataflow code as part of an JUnit test class

```java
@Test
public void dataFlowGenerator() {
  DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
  options.setRunner(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.class);
  options.setStagingLocation("gs://mybucket/lt");
  options.setProject("myProject");
  Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("sup1", "sup2", "sup3");
  p.apply(Create.of(list)).apply(ParDo.of(new generate())).apply(
      TextIO.Write.to("gs://mybucket/lt/df.txt"));
}


private class generate extends DoFn<String, String> implements Serializable {

  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    new DoFn<String, String>() {
      @Override
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        c.output(c.element());
      }
    };
  }
}
```

This outputs nothing (just an empty file df.txt-00000-of-00001) in the file mentioned in cloud storage. I was expecting processElement would be called for every string item in the list and they will be outputted to the output file.

How do I generate millions of records with random strings. In this case the dataflow does not  really need to have any input source. It should be able to just transform some seed string and output.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, you don't need to do that `ParDo` at all. Your transform is just the identity transform - you can just feed the output of `Create` right into `TextIO.Write`.

But I also want to clarify why you are not seeing goutput: Your `DoFn` subclass has a `processElement` method that creates another `DoFn` and just discards the value. You would want to write this instead:

```java
private class Generate extends DoFn<String, String> implements Serializable {

  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    c.output(c.element());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What create takes is a list of strings from in memory. is there any way I can write them to files and feed it because I need almost 1 billion lines of CSV to be generated

Comment: Can you create a new question with some details about how you want to generate the data?

Comment: Done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084252/create-large-csv-data-using-google-cloud-dataflow